# Occasionally getting "Document already exists" when simply using collection's add method

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have recently started to see this error more and more often and not too sure where I would start looking: `FirebaseError: [code=already-exists]: Document already exists`. Does anyone know what would cause this? Like some stale client database or connection that maybe attempted a retry? All I am doing is something like this: `firestore.collection('locations').add({..})`. This is using the Firestore Client SDK and I do not see this from all clients, but just some. The caller of this method is outside of my control as it's being triggered from the device/browser.